# Trouble with mixing quotes in SWFObject addvariable call

Tags: flash, video, swfobject

I am using SWFObject to play a flash SWF file.  The SWF file supports several flash variables.  When I try to pass a complex value for one of the flash variables that contains a mixture of single and double quotes, something bad happens when SWFObject writes the fully rendered content to the DIV set aside for the flash object.

Here is the code below, showing the DIV named *flashcontent* that SWFObject writes the rendered content into, and the Javascript code that interacts with SWFObject:

```
   <!-- Div that will receive the Flash object.  This DIV is written to by SWFObject.js.  Therfore It's name must match the name
            in the so.write() statement below. -->
    <div id="flashcontent">
    </div>

    <!-- Div that will receive the Flash object.  This DIV is written to by SWFObject.js.  Therfore It's name must match the name
            in the so.write() statement below. -->
    <div id="flashcontent">
    </div>

    <!-- Create the tag cloud -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var so = new SWFObject("/Content/flash/tagcloud.swf", "tagcloud", "600", "400", "7", "#336699");

        so.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
        so.addVariable("mode", "tags");
        so.addVariable("distr", "true");
        so.addVariable("tcolor", "0xff0000");
        so.addVariable("hicolor", "0x000000");

        so.addVariable("tagcloud", "<tags><a href='javascript:showMessage(\"tag1\");' style='9'>tag one</a><a href='javascript:showMessage(\"tag2\");' style='12'>Tag two</a></tags>");
        so.write("flashcontent");
    </script>
```

As you can see I try to escape the double-quotes around the string parameters being passed to my Javascript showMessage() function.  However, when the *flashcontent* DIV content is rendered, it looks like this:

```
<div id="flashcontent"><embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="/Content/flash/tagcloud.swf" width="600" height="400" id="tagcloud" name="tagcloud" bgcolor="#336699" quality="high" wmode="transparent" flashvars="mode=tags&amp;distr=true&amp;tcolor=0xff0000&amp;hicolor=0x000000&amp;tagcloud=<tags><a href='javascript:showMessage(" tag1");'="" style="9">tag one<a href='javascript:showMessage("tag2");' style="12">Tag two</a>"/></div>
```

The first escaped double-quote is interpreted as an unescaped double-quote and that breaks the formatting resulting in an invalid hyperlink.  If I take out the unescaped quotes, this is what the content looks like:

```
<div id="flashcontent"><embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="/Content/flash/tagcloud.swf" width="600" height="400" id="tagcloud" name="tagcloud" bgcolor="#336699" quality="high" wmode="transparent" flashvars="mode=tags&amp;distr=true&amp;tcolor=0xff0000&amp;hicolor=0x000000&amp;tagcloud=<tags><a href='javascript:showMessage(tag1);' style='9'>tag one</a><a href='javascript:showMessage(tag2);' style='12'>Tag two</a></tags>"></div>
```

Now the formatting is proper and the web page is sound.  Naturally, I get "undefined" when my ShowMessage() function shows the message because *tag1* and *tag2* are not valid Javascript variable names.

Does the SWFObject *addvariable* method do anything unorthodox to escaped double-quotes?  How can create a string that *addvariable* will accept so that I can get double-quotes around my Javascript method parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using a very outdated edition of swfobject. try the latest version (2.2) or the 2.3 beta, they each handle params differently under the hood. 2.3 might work best in your case.

Comment: Thanks.  I can't seem to find SWFObject 2.3, only 2.2.  Do you have a link?

Comment: 2.2 did the job.  You were right about the old copy of SWFObject being problematic.  If you ever find a link to 2.3, please post.  Thanks again.